# react-native-fbsdk managing dependency

Tags: react-native, xcode8, react-native-ios

I did this:

```
react-native init YourApp
cd YourApp
react-native install react-native-facebooksdk
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

[image: xCode project folder structure]

After link, was linked into project RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj, If I run Build as the image is, I get an error: `ld: library not found for -lRCTFBSDK`

If I move frameworks inside `.../Libraries/RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj/Frameworks/` to `.../Libraries/` the build runs OK.

But when I push my code to my CI (buddybuild) I get an error that CI couldn't found frameworks. There others react-native dependencies that managed automatically iOS dependencies. Is there a way that should able to use frameworks as is, but changing code config to look into correct folder?

Comment: Did you end up getting it to work on buddybuild? I'm using carthage (not cocoapods) and it does not support carthage

Comment: Nops, I don't. But I would like to try Carthage. It seems that buddybuild has integration with carthage. Did ou tried http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/carthage ?

Comment: buddybuild supports carthage yes (I'm using carthage ATM with buddybuild and it works fine). But the react-native fbsdk does not support carthage which means we cannot use it :\

Answer (score 1):

You should either install the Facebook SDK for iOS via CocoaPods as described [here](https://medium.com/@hmovielabs/day-10-using-facebook-sdk-in-react-native-app-57405cfead63). Or download it and manually link the required Facebook frameworks to your Xcode project.
Start [here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts) for the later.